# i would like to populate one drop down list using another drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, html.dropdownlistfor

i tried a code from a video and got an error :

[This is the Error when i click my drop down to display the states from country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9bXe.png)

this is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Submit()
                    {
                        List<Country> allCountry = new List<Country>();
                        List<State> allState = new List<State>();
                        using (DropDownTestEntities1 dc = new DropDownTestEntities1())
                        {
                            allCountry = dc.Countries.OrderBy(a => a.CountryName).ToList();
                        }
                        ViewBag.CountryID = new SelectList(allCountry, "CountryID", "CountryName");
                        ViewBag.StateID = new SelectList(allState, "StateID", "StateName");
                        return View();
                    }
         [HttpPost]
         [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] // this is for prevent CSRF Attack
         public ActionResult Submit(Feedback fb)
         {
             List<Country> allCountry = new List<Country>();
             List<State> allState = new List<State>();

             using (DropDownTestEntities1 dc = new DropDownTestEntities1())
             {
                 allCountry = dc.Countries.OrderBy(a => a.CountryName).ToList();
                 if (fb != null && fb.CountryID > 0)
                 {
                     allState = dc.States.Where(a => a.CountryID.Equals(fb.CountryID)).OrderBy(a => a.StateName).ToList();
                 }
             }

             ViewBag.CountryID = new SelectList(allCountry, "CountryID", "CountryName", fb.CountryID);
             ViewBag.StateID = new SelectList(allState, "StateID", "StateName", fb.StateID);


             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 using (DropDownTestEntities1 dc = new DropDownTestEntities1())
                 {
                     dc.Feedbacks.Add(fb);
                     dc.SaveChanges();
                     ModelState.Clear();
                     fb = null;
                     ViewBag.Message = "Successfully submitted";
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 ViewBag.Message = "Failed! Please try again";
             }
             return View(fb);
         }

         [HttpGet]
         public JsonResult GetStates(string countryID = "")
         {
             List<State> allState = new List<State>();
             int ID = 0;
             if (int.TryParse(countryID, out ID))
             {
                 using (DropDownTestEntities1 dc = new DropDownTestEntities1())
                 {
                       allState = dc.States.Where(a => a.CountryID.Equals(ID)).OrderBy(a => a.StateName).ToList();
                     //allState = dc.States.Where(a => a.CountryID.Equals(ID)).OrderBy(a => a.StateName).ToList();
                 }
             }
             if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
             {
                 return new JsonResult
                 {
                     Data = allState,
                     JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                 };
             }
             else
             {
                 return new JsonResult
                 {
                     Data = "Not valid request",
                     JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                 };
             }
         }

                }
            }
```

this is my model code :

```
 public partial class Feedback
    {
        public int FeedbackID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide your fullname", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Mobile No")]
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select country", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "State")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select state", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public int StateID { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my view with my ajax code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Feedback", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Feedback</legend>
        @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
            <div style="border:solid 1px black">
                @ViewBag.Message
            </div>
        }
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNo)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, @ViewBag.CountryID as SelectList, "Select Country")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateID, @ViewBag.StateID as SelectList, "Select State")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateID)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script language="javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#CountryID").change(function () {
                            // this will call when Country Dropdown select change
                            var countryID = parseInt($("#CountryID").val());
                            if (!isNaN(countryID)) {
                                var ddState = $("#StateID");
                                ddState.empty(); // this line is for clear all items from State dropdown
                                ddState.append($("<option></option").val("").html("Select State"));

                                // Here I will call Controller Action via Jquery to load State for selected Country
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "@Url.Action("GetStates","Feedback")",
                                    type: "GET",
                                    data: { countryID: countryID },
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                                            ddState.append(
                                                    $("<option></option>").val(val.StateID).html(val.StateName)
                                                );
                                        });
                                    },
                                    error: function () {
                                        alert("Error!");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
    </script>
}
```

All i want is for my country selecteditem to populate my state with the link between the two. E.g. if i select South Africa, it must only display Gauteng, Cape Town etc.

Please can your'll help me with my error or provide guidance thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1: Try using `==` instead of using `.Equals()` because if `CountryID`is null, you'll throw an error.

Issue 2: Change

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
             {
                 return new JsonResult
                 {
                     Data = allState,
                     JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                 };
             }
```

to

```
        return Json(allState, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Possible Issue 3?
Try this as your success function:

```
                            success: function (data) {
                                $(data).each(function () {
                                    ddState.append(
                                            $("<option></option>").val(this.StateID).html(this.StateName)
                                        );
                                });
                            },
```

Comment: The states drop down still doesn't work but  the error doesn't show up at that point anymore. So thanks for that. Can you kindly assist me in telling me why it doesn't populate the state drop down from the Country.drop down selected option.

Comment: Also, make sure `data` is what you want